# Rank data in TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Data :

```
DECLARE @tblData TABLE (MediaID int,MediaTagName varchar(2000),MediaTypeName varchar(2000),keyitem varchar(2000),value varchar(2000))
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48229,'Primary','Video','videoid','1234')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48229,'Primary','Video','src','somesrc')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48229,'Primary','Video','url','someurl')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48211,'Secondary','Video','videoid','1234')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48211,'Secondary','Video','src','somesrc')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48311,'Primary','Video','videoid','123456')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48311,'Primary','Video','src','somesrc')
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (48311,'Primary','Video','url','someurl')
```

Query tried :

```
SELECT 
    MediaID, MediaTagName, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mediaid,mediatagname ORDER BY mediatagname) as rnk 
FROM 
    @tblData
```

I need to get data that is partitioned based on `MediaId` and `MedisTagName`. essentially the end result should be :

```
DECLARE @tblDataExpected TABLE (MediaID int,MediaTagName varchar(2000),MediaTypeName varchar(2000),keyitem varchar(2000),value varchar(2000),rnk int)
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48229,'Primary','Video','videoid','1234','1')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48229,'Primary','Video','src','somesrc','1')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48229,'Primary','Video','url','someurl','1')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48211,'Secondary','Video','videoid','1234','1')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48211,'Secondary','Video','src','somesrc','1')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48311,'Primary','Video','videoid','123456','2')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48311,'Primary','Video','src','somesrc','2')
INSERT INTO @tblDataExpected VALUES (48311,'Primary','Video','url','someurl','2')

SELECT * from @tblDataExpected
order by MediaID
```

Summary - The partition should be based off of mediatag and media id to generate the rank, however if there is a repeating `mediaTag` (for example "Primary") with a different media id, it should do an increment of the last rank it used for the primary with previous media ID and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `RANK` as you have duplicates in your partitions. This will only increase the rank number on distinct rows.

Secondly, the partition only needs to be on `MediaTagName` as you are wanting to increment for every distinct `MediaID` for each `MediaTagName`. Therefore `MediaID` moves to the `ORDER BY` criteria.

I believe the following produces the results you are after:

```
SELECT  td.MediaID,
        td.MediaTagName,
        td.MediaTypeName,
        td.keyitem,
        td.value,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MediaTagName ORDER BY MediaID) AS rnk
FROM    @tblData AS td
ORDER BY td.MediaID;
```